# How would one implement a 4-qubit CCCNOT gate (equivalent to controlled-Toffoli)?

Tags: quantum-gate

I've been meaning to implement Grover's Algorithm for the 3-bit case, wherein I need to implement a CCCNOT gate. How can this be done efficiently (i.e. as few Toffoli and/or CNOT as possible)?